# PayPal shop within Facebook iFrame

Tags: facebook, paypal, integration, same-origin-policy

As with all projects the goalposts have moved and I need some help with the easiest/quickest solution to implement.

Initially, I just needed to build a product catalogue site. Now, I need to include a PayPal cart and Facebook integration. The site needs to work within Facebook (Page Tabs) and independently, and I can't exclude Safari(and other) users (regarding the dreaded SOP). The extent of the Facebook integration is purely Page tabs, no log in required.

I see this working with Ajax and JSON (plus PHP), with something from PayPal to encrypt the data, POST it, then continue.

My questions: 
What PayPal service can I use that will work within the iFrame, that will cater for blocked cookies?
The best method to avoid SOP that I can think of is AJAX and JSON, but how would this work with PayPal.  Can I build the cart data when the user wishes to checkout?
I have used the popup window method to avoid the Third Party Cookie restricts, however, I have had issues Firefox still not reading the cookie data within a Facebook Page tab(iFrame).

Any help here is greatly appreciated.
Much thanks,
Simon